Integration contour of $\int_0^L\frac{e^{-ikx}\sin\left(nx\right)}{\sin(x)}dx$?
As the title says, I am trying to solve the Fourier integral
\begin{align}
I=\int_0^L\frac{ e^{-ikx}\sin\left(n x\right)}{\sin x}dx,
\end{align}
where $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $L$ if finite. I have experience with improper integrals and its complex extensions, but nothing related to this (finite contours).
I tried in vain to solve the above with real methods, however, it was impossible to obtain something. I suspect that complex analysis can save the day (residue theorem), however, reading the Wikipedia article and this discussion, I'm not sure how can I concretize the integration contour where I should integrate the complex extension of the latter integral. Moreover, I don't know if it's possible, so it's a guess.

Are there any restrictions on $L$? If not, you may as well be asking about the indefinite integral.

Thank you for the feedback. $L$ is finite.

Since the integrand is even in $n$, we may as well deal with the case that $n \geq 0$, and if $n = 0$, the integrand is $0$, so we may as well assume $n \geq 1$.
The ratio $\frac{\sin nx}{\sin x}$ is $U_{n - 1}(\cos x)$, where $U_{n - 1}$ is the $(n - 1)$st Chebyshev polynomial of the second kind, which has the same parity as $n - 1$. So, our integral is
$$I(n, k) := \int_0^L e^{-i k x} U_{n - 1}(\cos x) \,dx .$$
If we write $U_{n - 1}(z) = \sum_{m = 0}^{n - 1} a_m z^m$, then $$U_{n - 1}(\cos \theta) = \sum_{m = 0}^{n - 1} a_m \left[\frac12\left(e^{i x} + e^{-i x}\right)\right]^m,$$
hence the integrand $e^{-i k x} U_{n - 1}(\cos x)$ can be written as a linear combination of exponential functions $e^{-imx}$, each of which are easy to integrate. The original integral is real, so we may as well only keep track of the real parts of these latter integrals.
For example, $I(0, k) = 0$, $I(1, k) = \frac1k \sin k L$ (which has a removable singularity at $k = 0$, $I(1, 0) = L$), and
$$I(2, k) = \frac{\sin (k - 1) L}{k - 1} + \frac{\sin (k + 1) L}{k + 1} ,$$
(which has removable singularities at $k = \pm 1$, so that $I(2, \pm 1) = L + \frac12 \sin 2 L) .$

Since you describe the integral as a "Fourier integral", presumably you're particularly interested in the case $L = 2 \pi$ and $k \in \Bbb Z$, so that we're computing the coefficient of the Fourier series for a multiple of $\frac{\sin nx}{\sin x}$, and henceforth this answer treats that case.
Substituting $z = e^{i \theta}$ transforms the integral to a contour integral over the unit circle, $S^1$:
$$\int_0^{2 \pi} \frac{e^{-i k x} \sin n x}{\sin x} \,dx = \oint_{S^1} \frac{z^{-k} (z^n - z^{-n})}{z - z^{-1}} \cdot \frac{dz}{i z} = \frac1i \oint_{S^1} \frac{z^{2 n} - 1}{z^{n + k} (z^2 - 1)} \,dz .$$
The integrand has removable singularities at $\pm 1$, which we can ignore when integrating. The only possibly nonremovable singularity of the integrand is at $0$, so we can evaluate the integral using the Residue Theorem.

The Residue Theorem gives that the integral has value $$\frac1i \cdot 2 \pi i \operatorname{Res}\left(\frac{z^{2 n} - 1}{z^{n + k} (z^2 - 1)} , 0\right) = 2 \pi \operatorname{Res}\left(\frac{z^{2 n} - 1}{z^{n + k} (z^2 - 1)} , 0\right) .$$ We can rewrite the integrand as its finite Laurent series at $z = 0$: $$\frac{1}{z^{n + k}} \left(1 + z^2 + \cdots + z^{2 n - 2} \right) = z^{-n - k} + z^{-n - k + 2} + \cdots + z^{n - k - 4} + z^{n - k - 2} .$$ So, the residue (i.e., the coefficient of $z^{-1}$ in the above expansion) is $1$ if $-(n + k - 1) \leq 0 \leq n + k - 1$ and $n, k$ have the same parity, and $0$ otherwise. Assembling the ingredients gives: $$\int_0^{2 \pi} \frac{e^{-i k x} \sin n x}{\sin x} \,dx = \begin{cases}1, & |k| < |n| \quad \textrm{and} \quad n - k \equiv 1 \pmod 2 \\ 0, & \textrm{otherwise}\end{cases}$$


Can I kindly ask you to give me lights regarding the Laurent expansion? Because, according to my procedure
\begin{align}
\frac{z^{2n}-1}{z^{n+k}\left(z^2-1\right)}=\frac{1-z^{2n}}{z^{n+k}}\sum_{p=0}^{\infty}z^{2p}&=\sum_{p=0}^\infty \left(z^{2p-n-k}-z^{2p+n-k}\right)\
&=z^{-n-k}+z^{2-n-k}+\dots -z^{n-k}-z^{2+n-k}-\dots,
\end{align}
we have differences. Or maybe I am missing something.

Notice that for $m \geq n - k$, the first term in the summand contributes a $z^m$ and the second a $-z^m$. Another way to see this expansion is to write $$\frac{z^{2n} - 1}{z^2 - 1} = 1 + z^2 + \cdots z^{2 n - 4} + z^{2 n - 2} .$$

Perhaps this is trivial, but can you explain me how expansion $(z^{2n}-1)/(z^2-1)=1+z^2+\dots + z^{2n-4}+z^{2n-2}$ is obtained? Sorry.

Just multiply both sides by $z^2 - 1$.

Yeah, it was very obvious, but dizziness acts in mysterious ways. Thank you!
